# mysqlNotSupportedOpts error using NagVis with Icinga

Tags: backend

I am trying to use NagVis with Icinga, but i can't seem to configure the backend well.

I must use the **ido2db backend** of NagVis so i configure it using the website indications located here : http://docs.nagvis.org/1.6/en_US/backend_ndomy.html

All of the parameters ( dbhost, dbport, dbname, dbuser, dbpass, dbprefix, dbinstancename, maxtimewithoutupdate) are set accordingly with my idomod.cfg and ido2db.cfg of icinga.

When trying to add an host on a map i get the following : "**Unable to fetch data from backend - falling back to input field.**" 
And adding an host anyway makes it have this summaryoutput : "**Problem (backend idomy_1) : mysqlNotSupportedOpts : {"BACKENDID":"ndomy_1"}** "

I can't seem to find any informations about the *mysqlNotSupportedOpts* error

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I wrote this wiki article, it worked for me. Can you verify that all required database configurations are set and update your initial question with those too?

https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/NagVis#NagVis-ConfigurationwithIcingaIDOUtils

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have all of thoose plus dbhost="localhost" and dbinstancename="default" . Same error